# PHP - Dynamically create methods in a class by an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, extends

I have a class that extends another class with unknown methods. Here is the base of the class:

```
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass {     
}
```

I also have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
  'aFunctionName' => 'My Value',
  'anotherFunctionName' => 'My other value'
);
```

It contains the `classname` and a `value`. The question is how I can use them in the extended class, creating the classes on demand, dynamically.

### Results

Here is the result of how the PHP should read the result of my array.

```
class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass {

  public function aFunctionName() {
    return 'My value';
  }

  public function anotherFunctionName() {
    return 'My other value';
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create extended methods by an array like this?

Comment: You could use [runkit_method_add](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to create magic methods, like this :

```
class Foo {

    private $methods;

    public function __construct(array $methods) {
        $this->methods = $methods;
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        if(isset($this->methods[$method])) {
            return $this->methods[$method];
        }
    }
}

$array = array(
  'aFunctionName' => 'My Value',
  'anotherFunctionName' => 'My other value'
);

$foo = new Foo($array);
echo $foo->aFunctionName();
```

Comment: Added as a plugin. https://github.com/tovic/p-h-p-dynamic-methods